# Automatically converting an A* into a B*

Tags: c++, proxy, smart-pointers, conversion-operator

Suppose I'm given a class `A`.  I would like to wrap pointers to it into a small class `B`, some kind of smart pointer, with the constraint that a `B*` is automatically converted to an `A*` so that I don't need to rewrite the code that already uses `A*`.

I would therefore want to modify `B` so that the following compiles...

```
struct A {
  void foo() {}
};

template <class K>
struct B {
  B(K* k) : _k(k) {}
  //operator K*() {return _k;}
  //K* operator->() {return _k;}
private:
  K* _k;
};

void doSomething(A*) {}

void test() {
  A a;
  A* pointer_to_a (&a);
  B<A> b (pointer_to_a);
  //b->foo();             // I don't need those two...
  //doSomething(b);

  B<A>* pointer_to_b (&b);

  // Following represents existing code I don't want to change...
  pointer_to_b->foo();       // 'foo' : is not a member of 'B<K>'
  doSomething(pointer_to_b); // 'doSomething' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'B<K> *' to 'A *'
}
```

Note that `B` inheriting from `A` is not an option (instances of `A` are created in factories out of my control)...

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered existing smart pointer implementations, like `auto_ptr` or `shared_ptr`?

Comment: Converting to an `A*` is not the only responsibility I want from `B`: it must, in particular, inherit from other classes.  And I would have to change the code currently using `A*`, wouldn't I?

Comment: So, why are your operators commented out?

Comment: They allow the first two conversions (from `B` to `A*`) that I don't need.  They don't allow converting a `B*` to `A*`.

Comment: If `B` is a smart pointer, then using a pointer to `B` is like using a double pointer (**). Why would you want automatic dereferencing here? In what scenario would you not want to pass a smart pointer by value? (This is not a rethorical question)

Comment: I have to use the `B` in template classes that currently only work with pointers, not instances.  I tried to change them, but did not succeed yet.

Comment: I tried to store a reference to `A` instead of a pointer, and make `B` convert to `A` so that `B*` would convert to `A*`, but I could not get this to compile...

Comment: It looks like mission impossible to me.

Comment: Could you clarify what is the code you don't want to modify? 
Can pointer_to_b be declared in another way? 
What was the preceding declaration of B?

Comment: It would be a good thing if you explained why you accepted the answer you accepted.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it seemed to me the closest to the solution I would have liked, which does not seem to exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of pointer_to_b is *pointer* to B, which is a type you cannot modify; it's implemented by the compiler.

You can do (*pointer_to_b)->foo(), which will do the right thing (assuming you have the overridden operator->()). However, that won't let the other code do the right thing, if you pass pointer_to_be into it.

Also let me add that you can override operator& on B to return an A*, which might solve your problem, depending on the specific use cases.

Comment: I wouldn't want to have to update all the existing code... :(

Comment: My suggestion does not require you to update all the code, if it's OK for operator& on B to return an A*.

Answer (score 2):

What about function `get()` as in `boost::shared_ptr`?

```
template <class K>
struct B {
  B(K* k) : _k(k) {}
  K* get() { return _k;}
private:
  K* _k;
};
```

Then you could use it as follows:

```
pointer_to_b->get()->foo();      
doSomething(pointer_to_b->get());
```

Answer (score 0):

The operators you have commented out in your `struct B` look like they should make it do what you want... why are they commented out?  Does it not work when they're uncommented, and if not, can you post the errors?

Comment: Adding those operators allows the two conversions that I commented out because I don't need them.  Uncommenting those operators does not change the errors that appear on the last two lines.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall the way `shared_ptr` gets around the issue I think you have is that you never pass around a `shared_ptr*`, you pass around a `shared_ptr` object.  That way the `operator->` works because it is being called on the object, not the pointer to the object.  I recommend that you pass around `B<A>` instead of `B<A>*`.  Who cares if the wrapper class is a pointer or not, as long as it represents a pointer to A it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

B inheriting from A **is** an option, this compiles (VS 2008 at least):

```
struct A { 
  void foo() {} 
}; 

template <typename  T> 
struct B : T
{ 
  B(const T& t) : T(t) 
  {} 
}; 

void doSomething(A*) {} 

void test() { 
  A a; 
  B<A> b (a); 

  B<A>* pointer_to_b (&b); 

  // Following represents existing code I don't want to change... 
  pointer_to_b->foo();       
  doSomething(pointer_to_b); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work from my point of view

```
struct A {
  void foo() {}
};

template <class K>
struct B {
  B(K* k) : _k(k) {}
  operator K*() {return _k;}
  K* operator->() {return _k;}
private:
  K* _k;
};

void doSomething(A*) {}

void test() {
  A a;
  A* pointer_to_a (&a);
  B<A> pointer_to_b (pointer_to_a);

  // Following represents existing code NOT CHANGED
  pointer_to_b->foo();       
  doSomething(pointer_to_b);

}
```